# How can I pass arguments to my protractor.conf from console/bash/cmd?

Tags: javascript, bash, protractor, automated-tests

using a standard protractor.conf.js file, I would like to be able to run different spec files each time I run it.

```
capabilities: {

    browserName: 'chrome',

    specs: [XXXXXX],

    exclude: []

},
```

My question is, is it an option to run the test using 'protractor protractor.conf.js' via terminal/bash and add arguments that will fill in the specs value, in the same line? If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this-

```
 protractor config.js --specs 'specs/spec.js'
```

or to run multiple specs

```
protractor config.js --specs 'specs/spec1.js,specs/spec2.js'
```

you can also run test suite or suites

```
protractor config.js --suite your-suite-name
protractor config.js --suite suite1,suite2,suite3
```

please refer this [link](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L230) on how write specs in suite config option